# How to find the roots of a sum of divisions of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, summation, roots

How can I find those x values in which this function becomes f(x)=0?

I have 4 vectors of length N: A, B, C, D, and

$$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^N { x\cdot A_i - B_i  \over (x\cdot C_i - D_i)^3 }$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Are the coefficients all positive, or at least $A$ and $C$? Are the entries sorted so that the poles $D_i/C_i$ occur in ascending order?

Comment: No, there is not any order in the poles, and the coefficients are not positive